# how to make AFNetworkReachabilityStatus the first priority of my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I've made a function, called initnetwork in which I try to see if the network is reachable or not, and I call this function in my viewDidLoad, that's the first thing I do.

```
-(void)initNetwork {
    mainManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    mainManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 30;
    backgroundTaskManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    mainImgManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    backgroundImgManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [MainView addSubview:labelForRefresh];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        [defaults setInteger:status forKey:@"networkStatus"];
        if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {
            [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"reachability"];
            labelForRefresh.hidden = true;
        }
        else {
            [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"reachability"];
            [self indicatorStop];
            labelForRefresh.hidden = NO;
            [self hide_button];
            [self hidden_button];
        }
        [self getNetworkAction];
    }];
}
```

The probleme is, that it is not waiting for the return of setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock, and keep going through my viewDidLoad, initialising many stuff, that I don't want to.

I've tried to put some 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});

around, but it doesn't seems to work.
do someone have an explanation or a hint for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code, that depends on block completion inside of `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:` like this:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        [defaults setInteger:status forKey:@"networkStatus"];
        if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) {
           // put your  viewdidload code here (that depends on block completion)
        }
        else {
            // code
        }
        [self getNetworkAction];
    }];
```